# TypeError Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectRaw() must be of the type array

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo una búsqueda y me funciona, ahora necesito hacer un `JOIN` para que me haga la búsqueda en la otra tabla, cuando lo hago me dice que hay ambiguedad (Realmente si, porque coinciden los nombres de los campos en ambas) para solucionarlo pensé en `SelectRaw` pero me da un error:

Mi Controlador:

```
$visits = Visit::join('users', 'visits.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                    ->selectRaw('visits.first_name as first_name', 'visits.last_name as last_name', 'users.first_name as firstname','users.last_name as lastname')
                    ->groupBy('firstname', 'lastname', 'first_name', 'last_name')
                    ->search($request->visits)
                    ->paginate(12);
```

Mi Scope:

```
public function scopeSearch($query, $find)
{
    $search = explode(" ", $find);
    $total = count($search);

    $array = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++ ) {
         if( $i == 0 ) {
              $array = $query->where(DB::raw("CONCAT(code, ' ', first_name, ' ', last_name, ' ', phone, ' ', dni)"), "LIKE", "%".Stemm_es::stemm($search[$i])."%");
          } else {
              $array = $array->orWhere(DB::raw("CONCAT(code, ' ', first_name, ' ', last_name, ' ', phone, ' ', dni)"), "LIKE", "%".Stemm_es::stemm($search[$i])."%");
          }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

El error:

```
TypeError
Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::selectRaw() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\covid\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la documentación, [`selectRaw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods) recibe segundo parámetro **opcional**, pero tú le estás enviando más de dos parámetros. Esto:

```
->selectRaw('visits.first_name as first_name', 'visits.last_name as last_name', 'users.first_name as firstname','users.last_name as lastname')
```

Debería ser:

```
->selectRaw('visits.first_name as first_name, visits.last_name as last_name, users.first_name as firstname, users.last_name as lastname')
```